# Change the default system highlight color

Tags: macos, system-settings, ui

Is it possible to change the default highlight color in Chrome and other Mac OS X Applications system wide?

How do I customize the default setting in apps like TextEdit or Mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences > General`. Click on `Highlight Color`.
You can even choose a custom color using `Other...`

If you are bored of the default Blue, you can change it to one of your taste.

[image: change highlight color on Mac OS X]

[image: highlight color 1]

[image: highlight color 2]